# How do I do a calculation...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example if I make 40 dollars in January then keep that 40 in February but add an additional 40... Then in March I have 80 (40 and additional 40) then add another $40.

How do I do that calculation for instance for 5 years?

```
J.     F.    M.   A.  M.
40.   40.  40.  40.  40
      40.  40.  40.  40
           40.  40.  40
                40.  40
                     40
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a function representing the culmative amount of money you make. Because you are earning 40 dollars extra each month, a linear function would be appropriate, $f(x)=40x$, to be precise, where $x$ is that amount of months. So in 5 years, $$f(5years)=40\cdot [12\cdot 5]=40\cdot 60=2400$$ dollars earned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure I understand what you're asking, but it looks like you just need to multiply 40 by the number of months in the period.

Comment: Sounds right to me.